# USB flash drive does not support boot

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, firmware

I bought a Transcend USB flash drive (Jetflash 350, 16 GB) recently. My aim was to copy an image file (some FreeBSD ISO) on it and install FreeBSD on my machine. However, now I find that the flash drive does not support boot as mentioned [here](https://www.transcend-info.com/Support/FAQ-409). Is there any way I can get around this? Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Though there is no *factory support* for making it a boot drive, that should not pose a problem to enabling boot through any Linux installation tool, as long as it is formatted so that the PC can read it at boot-up.

*Any* USB drive of ~2 GB or larger, preferably formatted FAT32 (FAT might work for a smaller drive), should work. Testing FreeBSD or other Linux distro on it should do no harm.

That said, there have been some messages about [slow performance in FreeBSD of the JetFlash](http://git.net/ml/freebsd-usb/2010-08/msg00106.html), stating it can be helped by enabling *async* cache. However, this is only an issue when writing to the device... running Linux from it (without caching data to a partition), or using it to install Linux, should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems that my BIOS / firmware was quite old and it was not supporting a 16 GB flash memory... that's the reason it was not showing in the BIOS boot menu as well. I have updated my BIOS and it's working fine now.

Comment: Good! Did the installation succeed?

Comment: Well I am not getting time to sit down and do the installation (I am a lazy kind of person). Since now I am able to boot from the flash drive, I don't think there will be any problem. Anyways, will keep you posted.